# Webpage with Chrome page switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, web-developer-toolbar

I have to make a web page which shows two web pages combine and have a page switcher just 
like present in chrome to switch between most visited websites and applications.
I need helping links for making such webpage. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What do you have already? What do you need help with specifically?

Comment: i have nothing right now.but i know the html,css,javacscript and jquery+jquery plugins.but i am unable to find a plug-in like chrome page switcher. I specifically need to implement such/same page switcher in my webpage.